# How to prevent webBrowser to fire when opening form in C#

Tags: c#, messagebox

In my windows form application i have five tabs in each I have webBrowser. When page loads I got MessageBox showing that page is loaded (I need this) like this:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
        return;

    MessageBox.Show("1st page loaded.", "1st page loaded.");
}
```

My problem is when I open my application I always get five messages that all my pages are loaded, how to prevent webBrowsers to fire, or dont show messages when I load application.

Comment: Did you set the URL property of all the webBrowser?

Comment: no I leaved it empty;

Comment: I never used this and did not write forms application since school :) Probably you should search for different event on which you can call MessageBox.show..., maybe something like tab focus or something like that. Control.VisibleChanged maybe this.

Comment: The DocumentCompleted event will occur if one of those properties is set or methods is called: Url, DocumentText, DocumentStream, Navigate, GoBack, GoForward, GoHome, GoSearch.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set the URL the URL will be empty. Therefore checking for empty should solve the problem.

If you do not set the URL the URL of the Event and of the Webbrowser will be the same (empty)

```
 if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
```

Comment: I do not set URL but messagebox appears, becouse he think that empty page is loaded.

Comment: the url is empty always, only after button click webbrowser get URL from text file.